# How do I set the "name" attribute in an email

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail

I am sending mail with Java mail and an SMTP server. I want to be able to change the "name" that the recipient sees when they get an email message - not simply the prefix of the email address (the bit before @).

I suspect I need to change or add one of the 'props.put();' settings but I can't work out which one.

```
public class Email {

    private final String HOST = "mail.myserverr.com";
    private final String USER = "me+myserver.com";
    private final String FROM = "me@myserver.com";
    private final String PASS = "mypass";
    private final String PORT = "25";
    private final String AUTH = "true";

    @Test
    public void sendMail(){
        String[] to = {"mygmail@gmail.com","me@myservercom"};
        sendMessage(to,"Let's go","What's up");

    }

    public void sendMessage(String[] to, String subject, String msg) {

        Properties props = System.getProperties();
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); // added this line
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", HOST);
            props.put("mail.smtp.user", USER);
            props.put("mail.smtp.password", PASS);
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", PORT);
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", AUTH);
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", PORT);
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");


        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        try {
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(FROM));

        InternetAddress[] toAddress = new InternetAddress[to.length];

        // To get the array of addresses
        for( int i=0; i < to.length; i++ ) { // changed from a while loop
            toAddress[i] = new InternetAddress(to[i]);
        }

        for( int i=0; i < toAddress.length; i++) { // changed from a while loop
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress[i]);
        }

        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setText(msg);

        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtps");
        transport.connect(HOST, USER, PASS);
            transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
            transport.close();

        } catch (AddressException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 32):

Typical address syntax is of the form `"user@host.domain"` or `"Personal Name <user@host.domain>"`.
You can use the same syntax for both FROM and TO field addresses.

**Example**:
Change following statement:
`String[] to = {"mygmail@gmail.com","me@myservercom"};`
to
`String[] to = {"Recipient1 Name <mygmail@gmail.com>","My Name <me@myservercom>"};`

You can also construct InternetAddress objects passing respective e-mailID and personal names as arguments.
**Example**:

```
String FROM = "my.email.id@my.server.domain";  
InternetAddress from = new InternetAddress( FROM, "Ravinder" );
```

Recipient will see sender name for display as `"Ravinder"` instead of `"my.email.id@my.server.domain"`

**Reference:** [**javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress**](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.html)

Comment: Thanks for the extra info on changing the recipient's name.

Comment: Is it possible to completely hide email id ? even after hovering the cursor

Comment: @Sadanand: Your question is no way related to Java Mail. Why don't you post a new question with the context on where the emailid appears and how hovering is related to it?

Comment: @Ankur: Let me hope you got the answer right. [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

Comment: can we change display email id as well? I mean different  auth id and display id.

Comment: @ManojTarkar: SMTP login can only be using authenticated id. And you can use any other id and display name for "From" field. But this can result to be a SPAM at the recipient's end. Read [Help prevent spoofing, phishing, and spam](https://support.google.com/a/topic/9061731?hl=en&ref_topic=9202)

Answer (score 13):

You need to change:

```
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(FROM));
```

to

```
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(FROM, "Company XYZ"));
```

> 

Documentation: [Class InternetAddress](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.html)

> InternetAddress
>
> ```
> public InternetAddress(String address,
>                    String personal)
>                    throws UnsupportedEncodingException
> ```
>
> Construct an InternetAddress given the address and personal name. The address is
> assumed to be a syntactically valid RFC822 address.
>
> Parameters:
>
> address - the address in RFC822 format
>
> personal - the personal name
>
> Throws: UnsupportedEncodingException