# javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted

Tags: email, jakarta-ee, gmail, jakarta-mail, wildfly

Mail service configuration in `standalone-full-ha.xml`.

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:mail:2.0">
    <mail-session name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/mail/Default" from="sender@gmail.com">
        <smtp-server outbound-socket-binding-ref="mail-smtp" ssl="true" username="User" password="password"/>
    </mail-session>
</subsystem>
```

The mail `Session` in turn references an SMTP host bound at localhost at port 465.

```xml
<outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
    <remote-destination host="smtp.gmail.com" port="465"/>
</outbound-socket-binding>
```

The actual password used in the configuration is an application specific password generated during "2-Step Verification" at `https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords`

After this configuration has been made, an attempted to send an email using the following code causes an exception to be thrown.

```
@Resource(mappedName = "java:jboss/mail/Default")
private Session mailSession;

public void init() throws AddressException, MessagingException {
    MimeMessage m = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
    Address from = new InternetAddress("sender@gmail.com");
    Address[] to = new InternetAddress[]{new InternetAddress("receiver@gmail.com")};

    m.setFrom(from);
    m.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, to);
    m.setSubject("Message Subject");
    m.setSentDate(new Date());
    m.setContent("Mail sent from app", "text/html");
    Transport.send(m);
}
```

The following exception is thrown.

```
07:48:36,906 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle] (default task-9) #{countryManagedBean.init}: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257 t70sm5413631pfi.8 - gsmtp
: javax.faces.FacesException: #{countryManagedBean.init}: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257 t70sm5413631pfi.8 - gsmtp

    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewAction.broadcast(UIViewAction.java:562)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.websockets.jsr.JsrWebSocketFilter.doFilter(JsrWebSocketFilter.java:151)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
    at org.omnifaces.facesviews.FacesViewsForwardingFilter.filterExtensionLess(FacesViewsForwardingFilter.java:128)
    at org.omnifaces.facesviews.FacesViewsForwardingFilter.doFilter(FacesViewsForwardingFilter.java:89)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:108)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
    at filter.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:33)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:122)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:108)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.DisableCacheHandler.handleRequest(DisableCacheHandler.java:33)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:51)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:56)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:72)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:282)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:80)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:172)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:774)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257 t70sm5413631pfi.8 - gsmtp

    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257 t70sm5413631pfi.8 - gsmtp

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:892)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:814)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:728)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:386)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:245)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:194)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:253)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at admin.bean.CountryManagedBean.init(CountryManagedBean.java:81)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:292)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 58 more
```

Using WildFly 9.0.2 final (the application using a self-signed SSL certificate should not be an issue here).

Comment: Gmail doesn't believe you've supplied the correct username or password.  Did you follow the link in the error message?  Did you try all the things Google suggests?  What happened?

Comment: I followed starting from `https://accounts.google.com/SmsAuthConfig` all steps to generating a password. It shows "2-Step Verification is: ON" at `https://accounts.google.com/b/0/SmsAuthSettings#devices`. Copy & pasted the generated password to the server configuration file, `standalone-full-ha.xml`. Is there anything missing there?

Comment: So...  you **didn't** follow the link in the error message?

Comment: I followed that link. I made an incorrect assumption. The XML attribute `username` was assigned the actual user name whereas it expects the sender's email address (I assumed that the sender's email address should correspond to the value of the `from` XML attribute as the name implies). Mails are sent after that change has been made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a configuration mistake made in an incorrect assumption. The XML attribute `username` expects the actual email address where the screen name of the corresponding sender's account was given hence, the exception. It works fine after it has been corrected as follows.

```xml
<mail-session name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/mail/Default" from="sender@gmail.com">
    <smtp-server outbound-socket-binding-ref="mail-smtp" ssl="true" username="sender@gmail.com" password="password"/>
</mail-session>
```

The actual password to be used in the configuration is an application specific password generated during "2-Step Verification" at `https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords` as already stated in the question.

The mail session `javax.mail.Session` can then be injected into any Java EE artifact like Servlets, Servlet filters, managed beans, EJBs, Message Driven Beans (MDB) etc using the `javax.annotation.Resource` annotation.

<sub>One thing which does not happen for some unknown reasons is the sender's name (label) as specified with the `from` XML attribute. It always sends the sender's email address as the sender name which is unexpected. Even doing,</sub>

```
Address from = new InternetAddress("admin@server.domain");
mimeMessage.setFrom(from);
```

<sub>does not help. I followed some patterns as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10171625/1391249) but it did not help either. It however, works in Java SE environment. It is nevertheless a different thing than the current question. Perhaps, I will ask a separate question later on.</sub>

---

**Additional :**

I prefer JMS queues to send mails asynchronously as a background process, since sending a mail may be delayed significantly for many reasons. The actual message along with the recipient's email address is sent through a JMS queue and the actual mail is delivered to a target mail server from within the receiving terminal of the corresponding queue like the following.

```
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "useJNDI", propertyValue = "true"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "java:jboss/exported/jms/emailQueue"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge")})
@RunAs("ROLE_ADMIN")
public class MailBean implements MessageListener {

    @Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/mail/Default")
    private Session mailSession; // javax.jms.Session

    @Override
    @PermitAll
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
    public void onMessage(Message message) {

        try {
            if (message instanceof ObjectMessage) {
                ObjectMessage objectMessage = (ObjectMessage) message;

                EmailUtil emailUtil = (EmailUtil) objectMessage.getObject();
                String receiver = emailUtil.getReceiver();
                String textMessage = emailUtil.getMessage();

                if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(receiver) && StringUtils.isNotBlank(textMessage)) {
                    MimeMessage mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
                    Address[] to = new InternetAddress[]{new InternetAddress(receiver)};

                    mimeMessage.setRecipients(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO, to);
                    mimeMessage.setSubject(emailUtil.getSubject(), "UTF-8");
                    mimeMessage.setSentDate(new Date());
                    mimeMessage.setText(textMessage, "UTF-8", "html");
                    Transport.send(mimeMessage);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("No message found.");
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Message is of wrong type : " + message.getClass().getName());
            }
        } catch (JMSException | MessagingException e) {
            Logger.getLogger(MailBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        }
    }
}
```

`EmailUtil` is a utility Java class holding necessary properties and implementing the `java.io.Serializable` interface (which is mandatory for sending serializable Java objects).

```
public final class EmailUtil implements Serializable {

    private String message;
    private String subject;
    private String receiver;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // Constructor(s) + getters + setters + hashCode() + equals() + toString().
}
```

In order to inject a `Queue`, I use an application scoped CDI managed bean for better reusability on the front side.

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class EmailQueueBean {

    @Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/exported/jms/emailQueue")
    private Queue queue;
    @Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/exported/jms/emailFactory")
    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    public EmailQueueBean() {}

    public void send(EmailUtil emailUtil) throws JMSException {
        try (Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection("admin@gmail.com", "admin_password");
                javax.jms.Session session = connection.createSession(false, javax.jms.Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
                MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue)) {
            ObjectMessage objectMessage = session.createObjectMessage(emailUtil);
            producer.send(objectMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

Inject this bean anywhere in any Java EE artifact, construct an instance of `EmailUtil` manually using `new` and invoke the `send()` method on behalf of the injected proxy instance of the managed bean passing through the instance of `EmailUtil` constructed.

The authentication using `username` / `password` as specified with the `createConnection()` method is not needed (nor `@RunAs("ROLE_ADMIN")` before the MDB), in case the security is disabled / not used in the hornetq server in the configuration.

**See also :**

- [JAAS authentication in JMS using WildFly : javax.jms.JMSSecurityException: HQ119032: User: null doesnt have permission=SEND on address {2}](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34098865/1391249)